# How to create a RichTextString using Apache POI framework in Java?

Tags: java, excel, excel-2003

How to create a RichTextString for Microsoft Excel, using Apache POI framework in Java SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html) and [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html) for HSSF and XSSF:

```
HSSFCell hssfCell = row.createCell(idx);
//rich text consists of two runs
HSSFRichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString( "Hello, World!" );
richString.applyFont( 0, 6, font1 );
richString.applyFont( 6, 13, font2 );
hssfCell.setCellValue( richString );

XSSFRichTextString s1 = new XSSFRichTextString("Apache POI");
s1.applyFont(boldArial);
cell1.setCellValue(s1);
```

Answer (score 12):

To keep abstraction on Workbook level (your code will work for both cases - HSSF and XSSF) you can write more intelligent code:

```
Workbook objWorkbook = /*pass workbook as a param*/;
RichTextString richText = objWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createRichTextString("yourstring");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html):

> Text boxes are created using a different call:
>
> ```
> HSSFTextbox textbox1 = patriarch.createTextbox(
>         new HSSFClientAnchor(0,0,0,0,(short)1,1,(short)2,2));
> textbox1.setString(new HSSFRichTextString("This is a test") );
> ```
>
> It's possible to use different fonts to style parts of the text in the textbox. Here's how:
>
> ```
> HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
> font.setItalic(true);
> font.setUnderline(HSSFFont.U_DOUBLE);
> HSSFRichTextString string = new HSSFRichTextString("Woo!!!");
> string.applyFont(2,5,font);
> textbox.setString(string );
> ```