# How to create text into Html using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can i convert the sentence into html using java program. Suppose if i have bold character or underline or superscript words while creating those how can i add html tag conditionally before and after that particular words.

What i think is read the excel file and then using string builder trying to append the whole sentence into p tag.

As i am very new into it . I dont understand how to iteratre through each word and check for various conditions

what i tried is this it cjust add the p tag in start and end , but does convert `help` in bold and `specific` in bold and underline

```
    public String getGeneralValue(Cell currentCell){
        switch (currentCell.getCellType()){
            case STRING:
                return currentCell.getStringCellValue();
            case NUMERIC:
                return String.valueOf((int) currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
            case BOOLEAN:
                return String.valueOf(currentCell.getBooleanCellValue()).toUpperCase();
            default:system.out.println("other than numeric and String");
        }
        return "";
    }
    public String setPType(Cell currentCell){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<p>");
        sb.append(getGeneralValue(currentCell));
        sb.append("</p>");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Here is the image an example

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure Excel allows for html formatting of its cells. You probably need to use rich text formatting instead.

Comment: Can you please tell how can i use  rich text formatting?

Comment: I'll let SO tell you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911934/how-to-create-a-richtextstring-using-apache-poi-framework-in-java/22296522